# How to download web resource using Digest authentication

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, http-authentication

What set of Windows API calls will allow downloading a web resource (specifically an XML document) when the site is protected using Digest authentication without having to enter a username and password?

I can use MSXML's “open” function on the `IXMLHTTPRequest` interface, but it requires a username and password to be supplied even though I'm logged on to the Windows domain server.

Internet Explorer can accomplish this task without requiring me to enter this information.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with this particular API. But it looks like there is a function to set a request header called **setRequestHeader** so have you tried adding the following line directly to the request header?

**Authorization: Basic %s\r\n**

Note: **%s** is **name:password** in base64 encoding.